# Passing a predicate that was passed in as a parameter

Tags: c#, linq, parameters, predicate

I'm having trouble with passing in a predicate to another function. This predicate would have been passed in as a parameter that is trying to call the second function. Below is a code snippet.

```
public IEnumerable<ViewModel> BuildModel<TPart, TRecord>(Expression<Func<TRecord, bool>> predicate) 
                where TPart : ContentPart<TRecord>
                where TRecord : ContentPartRecord
            {
                IEnumerable<ReportPart> items = GetList<ReportPart, ReportRecord>(predicate);
```

This issue is the predicate parameter, on the call to `GetList()` it keeps erroring, saying the call has some invalid arguments. The Get list call is:

```
 public IEnumerable<TPart> GetList<TPart, TRecord>(Expression<Func<TRecord, bool>> predicate)
            where TPart : ContentPart<TRecord>
            where TRecord : ContentPartRecord
```

I been trying changing the parameter a bunch of different ways trying to get this to work but I haven't had any success. Maybe I'm not understanding why the compiler thinks that 'predicate' is different than what `GetList()` is expecting.

**EDIT: more information**

```
ReportPart : ContentPart<ReportRecord>

ReportRecord : ContentPartRecord
```

ContentPart and ContentPartRecord are both base classes

Caller to BuildModels

```
List<ReportViewModel> model = _service.BuildReports<ReportPart, ReportRecord>(x => x.Id == 1).ToList();
```

BuildModels

```
public IEnumerable<ReportViewModel> BuildReports<TPart, TRecord>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TRecord, bool>> predicate)
            where TPart : ContentPart<TRecord>
            where TRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
            List<ReportViewModel> model = new List<ReportViewModel>();
            IEnumerable<ReportPart> reportParts = GetList<ReportPart, ReportRecord>(predicate);
            //do some stuff with reportParts
            return model;
    }
}
```

GetList

```
 public IEnumerable<TPart> GetList<TPart, TRecord>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TRecord, bool>> filter)
            where TPart : ContentPart<TRecord>
            where TRecord : ContentPartRecord
        {
            return filter == null ?
                Services.ContentManager.Query<TPart, TRecord>().List() :
                Services.ContentManager.Query<TPart, TRecord>().Where(filter).List();
        }
```

Comment: Could you please post the precise error message? Also can you please post the inheritance hierarchy for `ReportPart` and `ReportRecord`?

Comment: According to your error message, the issue is caused by the arguments that you're passing to BuildModel.  How are you calling it?

Comment: It's not erroring on the call to `GetList`. It's erroring on the call to `BuildModel`, which you haven't shown here.

Comment: Well, `BuildModel` is passing `Expression<Func<TRecord, bool>>` into a parameter that should be `Expression<Func<ReportRecord, bool>>`. I don't think that would work. Delegate covariance and contravariance is limited and here, you don't know what type `TRecord` will actually be. On top of that, you are wrapping that in an `Expression`, which will probably make the contravariance not work at all.

Comment: Co- and contravariance doesn't work that way. Try this line `var items = GetList<TPart, TRecord>(predicate);` that should work.

Comment: That was a wrong error message. I will update this question to be more complete and try out the suggested solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's impossible to know for sure what the best fix for your problem is, assuming one exists at all.

That said, variance problems generally come in two flavors: **1)** what you're doing is truly wrong and the compiler is saving you, and **2)** what you're doing is not provably correct, so you have to promise the compiler you know what you're doing.

If you're in the first category, then all is lost. You can't get this to work.

But if you're in the second category, you may be able to get your call to work by wrapping the original predicate in a new one that is compatible with the called method's requirements:

```
IEnumerable<ReportPart> items =
    GetList<ReportPart, ReportRecord>(r => predicate((TRecord)r));
```

That said, while it's possible that there's some important reason for you writing the code this way, given the little bit of code you've shown so far, it's not really clear why you're trying to take the generic predicate and force it into the specific type.

Depending on what's really going on in the rest of the code, a pair of generic methods like this would work better where you either **1)** go fully generic (i.e. don't force the type as `ReportRecord` in the call to `GetList()`), or **2)** you don't bother with the generic types at all (i.e. leave out `TPart` and `TRecord` from the `BuildModel()` method).

**Example of 1):**

```
public IEnumerable<ViewModel> BuildModel<TPart, TRecord>(
    Expression<Func<TRecord, bool>> predicate) 
        where TPart : ContentPart<TRecord>
        where TRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    IEnumerable<TPart> items = GetList<TPart, TRecord>(predicate);
}
```

**Example of 2):**

```
public IEnumerable<ViewModel> BuildModel(
    Expression<Func<ReportRecord, bool>> predicate)
{
    IEnumerable<ReportPart> items = GetList<ReportPart, ReportRecord>(predicate);
}
```

The mixing and matching, even if you can get it to work correctly, is often a sign that there's a more fundamental problem in the architecture, where generics are either being used where they shouldn't be, or are not being taken advantage as well as they should be.

If the above does not get you back on track, you really should improve the question by providing a minimal, complete code example.

Comment: changed to example two to get it working. I had tinkered with it so much, which is why you saw the mix of generic and non. Example two is actually what I wanted to achieve anyways.